# Using Socket.io with Service in Android

Tags: sockets, socket.io, android-service

I am developing an android app with node.js running on the backend. In the android app, I have multiple activities. I am opening a socket connection using Socket.io from the first activity. But the problem is that I don't know how to use that connection over multiple activities. I don't know how to implement this using Service. It would be great if you could answer with some code reference.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

socket.io has a chat app example implemented in android link below:
https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat

any way, for using socket.io in android, i think best way is using it inside a service something like this:

```
    public class ChatService extends Service {



    public void connectSocket() {
        try {
            IO.Options options = new IO.Options();

            socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.1:8080", options);
            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {

                }

            }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {

                }
            }).on("error", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {

                }
            });

            socket.connect();

        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        socket.disconnect();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: How will I use this in Activity? I am too weak at this part.

Comment: @SouvikBrahma you must call this service inside an activity for example onCreate() method of an activity, using this: startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChatService.class));

Comment: The whole part is not clear to me, how to connect this with activity